# SICStus Prolog atom to string

Tags: casting, prolog, iso-prolog

I need to convert a Prolog atom to an integer. For example:

```
?- convert('123', X).
X = 123
yes
```

I have seen some SO answers about that, but they rely on SWI-Prolog, and I am forced to use SICStus Prolog. Casting to string will also do the job, as I am aware of the `number_codes/2` predicate.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found an answer (in case you too need it):

```
atom_chars('123', Y), number_chars(X, Y).
```

Comment: This also works in B-Prolog and SWI-Prolog. And it's OK to accept your own answer.